# What is the memory size for convolutional neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am looking at http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

I don't understand why the memory size of layer 2 (CONV3-64: [224x224x64]) is 224x224x**64**

1. I understand that there are 64 filters of size 3x3 but why is the input size multiplied by 64?
2. Why the number of weights in layer (CONV3-128) are (3x3x64)x128 and not
   (3x3x64x64)x128 ? (the weights from the previous layer times the new 128 filters)?

.

```
INPUT: [224x224x3]        memory:  224*224*3=150K   weights: 0
CONV3-64: [224x224x64]  memory:  224*224*64=3.2M   weights: (3*3*3)*64 = 1,728
CONV3-64: [224x224x64]  memory:  224*224*64=3.2M   weights: (3*3*64)*64 = 36,864
POOL2: [112x112x64]  memory:  112*112*64=800K   weights: 0
CONV3-128: [112x112x128]  memory:  112*112*128=1.6M   weights: (3*3*64)*128 = 73,728
CONV3-128: [112x112x128]  memory:  112*112*128=1.6M   weights: (3*3*128)*128 = 147,456
POOL2: [56x56x128]  memory:  56*56*128=400K   weights: 0
CONV3-256: [56x56x256]  memory:  56*56*256=800K   weights: (3*3*128)*256 = 294,912
CONV3-256: [56x56x256]  memory:  56*56*256=800K   weights: (3*3*256)*256 = 589,824
CONV3-256: [56x56x256]  memory:  56*56*256=800K   weights: (3*3*256)*256 = 589,824
POOL2: [28x28x256]  memory:  28*28*256=200K   weights: 0
CONV3-512: [28x28x512]  memory:  28*28*512=400K   weights: (3*3*256)*512 = 1,179,648
CONV3-512: [28x28x512]  memory:  28*28*512=400K   weights: (3*3*512)*512 = 2,359,296
CONV3-512: [28x28x512]  memory:  28*28*512=400K   weights: (3*3*512)*512 = 2,359,296
POOL2: [14x14x512]  memory:  14*14*512=100K   weights: 0
CONV3-512: [14x14x512]  memory:  14*14*512=100K   weights: (3*3*512)*512 = 2,359,296
CONV3-512: [14x14x512]  memory:  14*14*512=100K   weights: (3*3*512)*512 = 2,359,296
CONV3-512: [14x14x512]  memory:  14*14*512=100K   weights: (3*3*512)*512 = 2,359,296
POOL2: [7x7x512]  memory:  7*7*512=25K  weights: 0
FC: [1x1x4096]  memory:  4096  weights: 7*7*512*4096 = 102,760,448
FC: [1x1x4096]  memory:  4096  weights: 4096*4096 = 16,777,216
FC: [1x1x1000]  memory:  1000 weights: 4096*1000 = 4,096,000

TOTAL memory: 24M * 4 bytes ~= 93MB / image (only forward! ~*2 for bwd)
TOTAL params: 138M parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your first question is referring to the memory stored from a forward pass.**

1. The 64 in 224x224x64 belonging to the CONV3-64 layer, is there because when you pass through a single 224x224x3 image, it goes through 64 3x3x3 filters, and so 64 new images must be stored in memory to propagate the effect of these 64 filters into the network via the forward pass.

**Your second is referring to the weight parameters in the network.**

2. In the CONV3-128 layer, the input is 112x112x64, that means that if you want to apply a single 3x3 filter, you are actually applying a different one to each of the 64 input channels. You can think of the input as a 112x112x64 volume that is being filtered by 64 different 3x3 filters, which could just be thought of as a 3x3x64 volumetric filter, which will output a single 112x112 image. The output of this layer is set to be 128 channels, so you have to do this 128 times hence 128*64*3*3 weights in this layer.